# Build something similar to sciSpacy, but say for another domain

Tags: spacy

I want to build a model similar to sciSpacy, but for another domain. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to first make sure you have enough training data about your new domain. If you want to have a Named Entity Recognizer, you need texts annotated with named entities. If you want to have a parser, you need texts with dependency annotations. If you want a POS tagger, you need texts annotated with POS tags, etc.

Then you can create a new blank model, add the component(s) to them you need, and start training those:

```
nlp = spacy.blank("fr")
ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
nlp.add_pipe(ner)
ner.add_label("MY_DOMAIN_LABEL")
nlp.begin_training()
nlp.update(texts, annotations, drop=0.2)
```

This code snippet is not complete, because it really depends on what exactly it is you want to do. You can find more complete snippets in the documentation: https://spacy.io/usage/training

You might also be interested in the command-line utility to train new models, cf https://spacy.io/api/cli#train